# Yarn Distributed-shell + GPU not showing nvidia-smi on output

Tags: apache-spark, cluster-computing, hadoop-yarn, ubuntu-22.04, nvidia-smi

I have a hadoop/yarn multi-node cluster on Ubuntu 22.04 and I have added GPU resources to the cluster following the hadoop instructions here: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/UsingGpus.html

When I ran the command, "yarn jar hadoop-yarn-applications-distributedshell.jar 
-jar hadoop-yarn-applications-distributedshell.jar 
-shell_command /usr/bin/nvidia-smi 
-container_resources memory-mb=3072,vcores=1,yarn.io/gpu=2 
-num_containers 2"

it shows that the application was successful but there is not any nvidia-smi output. What could be causing this issue?

Im expecting to get something like this after running the application in YARN:

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 375.66                 Driver Version: 375.66                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla P100-PCIE...  Off  | 0000:04:00.0     Off |                    0 |
| N/A   30C    P0    24W / 250W |      0MiB / 12193MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  Tesla P100-PCIE...  Off  | 0000:82:00.0     Off |                    0 |
| N/A   34C    P0    25W / 250W |      0MiB / 12193MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID  Type  Process name                               Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+